# The underlying provider failed on Open EF6 iis

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, autofac

After I upgraded the program to .net 4.5, upgraded EntityFramework to the latest and used Autofac to make some adjustments to the application, I encountered this problem:
After the program has been running for a few days, it will suddenly start to report frequently:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast an object of type "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction" to type "System.Transactions.SafeIUnknown".。
   在 System.Transactions.Transaction.JitSafeGetContextTransaction(ContextData contextData)
   在 System.Transactions.Transaction.FastGetTransaction(TransactionScope currentScope, ContextData contextData, Transaction& contextTransaction)
   在 System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
   在 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetFromTransactedPool(Transaction& transaction)
   在 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   在 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   在 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   在 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   在 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   在 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   在 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   在 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   在 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   在 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
   在 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   在 System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

I think this should be caused by changing the program to dependency injection, but I created a counter in Dbcontext creation and Dispose, confirming that all Dbcontext has been dispose, I don't understand what went wrong
This is my connection string

```
Data Source=***; Initial Catalog=cloud; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Pooling=True; UID=sa;PWD=***;
```

In some places, I use transactions, but I rarely use them.

```
public TransResult UseTrans(Action<DbTransaction<TContext>> action)
        {
            if (currentTransHasError)
            {
                return new TransResult() { IsSuccess = false, Message = currentTransErrorMessage };
            }
            var result = new TransResult() { IsSuccess = true };
            bool isNested = true;
            try
            {

                if (currentContextTrans == null)
                {
                    isNested = false;
                    currentContextTrans = db.Database.BeginTransaction();
                }
                var trans = new DbTransaction<TContext>(this, isNested);
                action?.Invoke(trans);
                trans.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                result.Message = currentTransErrorMessage = e.Message;
                result.IsSuccess = false;
                currentTransHasError = true;
                if (currentContextTrans != null)
                {
                    currentContextTrans.Rollback();

                }

                // TODO: Handle failure
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!isNested)
                {
                    if (currentContextTrans != null)
                    {
                        currentContextTrans.Dispose();
                        currentContextTrans = null;
                    }
                    currentTransErrorMessage = string.Empty;
                    currentTransHasError = false;
                }
            }
            return result;

        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: are you using .Net Framework or .Net Core? i can assume you're using MVC 5 using .Net Framework and implemented DI. I have some encountered issues back then, i would suggest you use .Net Core (as DI is already part of the build), and select .Net Framework as platform, as .Net Core now supports .Net Framework.

Comment: If you use .Net Core, this will be a lot of work, and I am worried that I may encounter many unknown problems.@Jeff

Comment: yeah I undertstand, it goes both ways. implementing a DI on MV5 is somehow tricky too. I have been using Unity.MVC in my case for MVC5 projects, worked fine at my end using this DI implementation using Unity using this link -> 
https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

Comment: @mjwills, sorry for the confusion. what i meant was .Net Framework libraries can be used on a .Net Core environment, given it supports the .Net Core version. The user still has to select .Net Framework though when creating a new project in .NetCore, select the dropdown and chose .NetFramework -> https://clip2net.com/s/44yRac6

Comment: @mjwills I am not sure which part of my code may be problematic. I can't even reproduce the problem in the test environment (I did a stress test), I didn't find the law of it.

Comment: @mjwills It happens when I instantiate the DbContext. In many places I use using(var db = new DbContext), which causes nesting, but I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: do you use transaction ? it looks like you share the innerexception could you also share the exception and the part of the code where the exception occurs ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Yes, I used the transaction, but this error will happen anywhere, new DbContext, SaveChanges(), trans.Commit

Answer (score 0):

we had a similar issue and we resolved it by adding multiple active result set in database server.

"Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that works with SQL Server to allow the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. When MARS is enabled for use with SQL Server, each command object used adds a session to the connection."

Comment: Yeah, there are numerous ways to get "The underlying provider failed on Open." Please look at the inner exception and then decide if this still answers the question. MARS was already set you know.